# Linq Select All Items Matching Array

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data collection of type `IEnumerable<Objects.LabourHours>` containing labour records for various employees. I wish to filter the list and return only records for selected employees, which is specified by a list of `int[] employees` containing the `EmployeeID`s.

```
class LabourHours
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public int EmployeeID {get;set;}
    public int HoursWorked {get;set;}
}
```

How would I go about this? I am sure this has been asked before but I can't find anything similar on here. The closest I have found involves grouping the records by UserID, which is not what I need - I need the actual records.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can filter your list with LINQ `Where` using `Contains` method:

```
var result = list.Where(x => employees.Contains(x.EmployeeID));
```

Comment: hmm so simple! All the solutions I found online were a combination of .All() and .Any() which resulted in a grouped return value rather than individual items. Is it just me though or is this the wrong way round compared to all other Linq operations?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result to preserve the order of the `employees` array, you can use `Select` on the array. From the doc, it "Projects each element of a sequence into a new form", which is basically what you'd want to do in this case.

```
var result = employees.Select(e => labourHours.First(l => l.EmployeeID == e));
```

Use `FirstOrDefault` if all `employees` don't necessarily have an associated `labourHours` entry.